# Create a Eclipse Plug-in in Java 8

Tags: eclipse, java-8, rcp

I work on a plug-in that I want to create in Java 8. I see that Eclipse Luna requires Java 7. Does that create difficulties?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Luna requires Java 7 as a minimum. There is no problem using Java 8 for plugins.